# How to validate Paypal Express Checkout API Credentials (USERNAME, PASSWORD and SIGNATURE )

Tags: api, credentials, paypal

I am new in integration of paypal express checkout. I just want to validate API credentials like username password and signature if these are exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for you to validate any body else's API credentials.  If you're looking for your own you can find them in your PayPal profile under API Access, or you could just [use this tool](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run) which will return your API credentials directly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just want to know is there any way by which we can check that user api credentials exist.

Comment: Not other than logging into the account to look.

Comment: Marketplace platforms will let their partners enter API credentials, and that needs both credentials validation and permission validation.